# Quicksort C in-place partition does not work (Revision)

Tags: c, quicksort, in-place, partition

I get stack overflow errors, would appreciate it if anyone could point out to me where am I doing it wrong. C language, using Visual Studio compiler. Note that this is only a revision given to me by my lecturer. I think the rest of my code, eg. sorting is fine.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void QuickSort (int data[], int size);
void QuickSortHelp (int data[], int from, int to);

void QuickSort (int data[], int size)
{
    QuickSortHelp(data, 0, size-1);
}

void QuickSortHelp (int data[], int from, int to)
{

    if (from >= to)
        return;

    else
    {
        int pivot;
        int index;
        int temp;
        int left, right;

        pivot = data[from];
        left = from + 1;
        right = to;

        for (left = from + 1;left<= right;left++,right--)
        {

            if (data[left] > pivot)
            {

                if (data[right]<= pivot)
                {
                    temp = data[left];
                    data[left] = data[right];
                    data[right] = temp;
                }


            }

        }

        temp = data[from];
        data[from] = data[left];
        data[left] = temp;

        index = left;



        QuickSortHelp (data, from, index-1);
        QuickSortHelp (data, index+1, to);
    }
}


int main()
{
    int data[] = {4,5,3,8,2,6,1,7};
    int i;

    printf("Test");
    QuickSort (data, 8);

    while (i<=8)
    {
        printf("%d", data[i]);
        i++;
    }

    printf("Test done");
}
```

Comment: Can you post the "Stack Overflow" (pun intended. :P) error messages..?

Comment: One thing I see wrong right off the bat, you never initialize `i` in `main()` before entering your `while`-loop. Thus the loop is *undefined behavior*. Not the problem with QuickSort, but you shoudl fix it. I'll look at the rest. But I can see a problem with the for-loop in the partitioning loop already.

Comment: SO is not for code review. Do you have a concrete technical question?